# Disable a Button when Activity Start

Tags: android, button

I have some value Associated to my button Which is linked with the specific field in the my database.

How to disable the button (Without Clicking) if the field is not Null.

I tried to do this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
String service_id = "65";
String indate = "29/03/2018";
String intransit = "2018-03-21 15:00:00.000";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.Enter );

    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Background().execute();
            //new Enter().execute();
        }
    } );

}

private class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    String url;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        url = "http://localhost/check.php";

        try {
            URL urL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            conn.setDoInput( true );
            conn.setDoOutput( true );
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( out, "UTF-8" ) );
            String data = URLEncoder.encode( "service_id", "UTF-8" ) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode( service_id, "UTF-8" ) + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode( "indate", "UTF-8" ) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode( indate, "UTF-8")+ "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode( "intransit", "UTF-8" ) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode( intransit, "UTF-8");

            writer.write( data );
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();

            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in, "iso-8859-1" ) );
            String result = "";
            String line = "";

            while((line =reader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }
            reader.close();
            in.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.e(TAG, "Result ="+result);
        if(result.equals( "Disabled" )){
            button.setEnabled( false );
        }else{
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            button.setEnabled( false );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code :
Here when the Activity start the button is still enable and to disable it i have to click on it.

Please bare my English.

Thanks For any Help.

Comment: if(field != null){ button.setEnabled(false)}

Comment: Show your code..

Comment: Check now I have updated my post @Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android provides two ways to achieve the same -

```
1. button.setClickable(false)
```

Button will not respond to any click events if you use this.

```
2. button.setEnabled(false)
```

Using this is not only not clickable, but it also visually indicates that button is disabled.

And based on your null check(condition) you can easily achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Initially mark the enabled status of your button as false inside your xml layout and based on the condition make it true. @NikhilLohar

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Your welcome. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.Enter );
    if(field != null) {
        button.setEnabled(false); // Or use setClickable(false) if you still want to show the button as not opaque
    }

    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Background().execute();
            //new Enter().execute();
        }
    } );

}
```

A better practise is to hide the button instead disabling it but I don't know what you have to do, so use the code above

Comment: Both with setEnabled and setClickable?

Comment: Then check the Id of your button